# subprocess.Popen: Different buffering for stdin, stdout, stderr?

Tags: python, python-3.x, popen, buffering

I'm in need of setting the `stderr` stream in a [`Popen`](http://docs.python.org/py3k/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.Popen) call to line-buffered. I discovered the `bufsize` argument, but it applies to all of the `stdin`, `stdout`, and `stderr` files.

How do I adjust the buffering to be different for each file?

Comment: How about something like this: `out = subprocess.Popen(['ls'], stdout=subprocess.PIPE, bufsize=0)` and then, `cat = subprocess.Popen(['ls'], stdin=out.stdout,                   stderr=subprocess.PIPE, bufsize=1)`. In the first case, `stdout` is unbuffered, while the `stderr` with the same arguments is line buffered.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I assume you use PIPE for stderr? In that case, I think you can do something like this:

```
p = subprocess.Popen(..., stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
fd = p.stderr.fileno()
my_stderr = os.fdopen(os.dup(fd), 'rU', new_bufsize)
os.close(fd)
# use my_stderr from here on
```

Comment: Well I don't see any better wya to do it. Thanks.

Comment: Why duplicating the file descriptor ?

Answer (score 1):

If you intend to write `stdout`/`stderr` to a file in the end anyway and you just need the output to be unbuffered you could use the following:

```
LOG_FILE = codecs.open('somelog.txt', 'a', 'utf_8', buffering=0)

subprocess.Popen(ARGS, stdout = LOG_FILE, stderr = LOG_FILE).communicate()
```

Then the buffering used will be the one for the file, in this case: no buffering.